# If bump maps override face normals for lighting calculations, why do flat shaded bump mapped models look different from smooth-shaded bump mapped?

Tags: normals

I am confused in regards to this. From my understanding, a bump map sort of 'overrides' the normals provided by the mesh faces for lighting calculations.

I also know that in flat-shading, a pixel is shaded based on color calculated with the normal of its face only, while smooth-shading interpolates the normals calculated at each vertex per pixel and shades the pixel accordingly. As such, flat shaded faces have the same color throughout while smooth-shaded dont

A bump/normal map essentially shades the triangle per pixel just like smooth shading, but the normal used is taken from the map/texture as opposed to some  linearly interpolated vertex normal. So logically, since normal/bump maps do this overriding of the normals to be used for shading, one would expect that a smooth-shaded bump map model should look identical to a flat-shaded bump-mapped one

After all, in both a smooth and flat shaded bump mapped normal, the bump map overides the normal in both cases.

Yet here is what a smooth-shaded Bump mapped Suzzane looks like:
[image]

And this is what a flat-shaded bump mapped  Suzzane looks like:
[image]

The difference is very subtle but it is indeed there. What exactly causes them both to look different? Isnt a bump map overriding the mesh normals in each case?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/220408/110840

Comment: @AllenSimpson I still don't get it. From everything I've read, Tangent Space is (U,V,N) where N is the underlying _geometric_ normal of the shaded triangle. The normal encoded in the Tangent Space map _replaces_ the interpolated vertex normal due to smooth shading. The change-of-basis is calculated once per triangle, not once per pixel, for economy? In that case, I would expect the interpolated normal to be chucked out as irrelevant, and the smooth shading of the mesh to have no effect.

Comment: ..or is the tangent-space basis precalculated once-per-_vertex_, and then _that_ is interpolated across the triangle? That would make sense, and smooth-shading would still enable/disable the interpolation of what is considered to be the N-component of the map, in world space. That would explain it.

Comment: @Robin that could be, I've never dove into the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/vector/bump.html)

> The *Bump* node generates a perturbed normal from a height texture,
> for bump mapping. The height value will be sampled at the shading
> point and two nearby points on the surface to determine the local
> direction of the normal.

This makes sense if you think about it for a moment. The bump map cannot completely overwrite the original normal because the map image itself has no information about which way the normal is facing in 3 dimensions because it does not contain a 3d vector like a normal map does. It only contains height information, which Blender samples to get a direction vector which is combined with the original meshes normal vector to create the offset. That original mesh normal vector enters the *Bump* node via the unconnected **Normal** input, and is affected by shade smooth.

For example, if we sample the bump map and get a height of 20, then one unit* to the left we get a height of 25, and one unit up we get a height of 30, we can make three points: (0, 0, 20), (1, 0, 25),and (0, 1, 30) from which we can do a little linear algebra and come up with a direction vector like (-0.45, -0.89, 0.09) which is then combined the mesh normal to get the final vector. **

```
a = Vector( (0, 0, 20) ) 
b = Vector( (1, 0, 25) ) 
c = Vector( (0, 1, 30) ) 

n=(b-a).cross(c-a)
n.normalize()
```

To give an example, we take a default cube with a bevel modifier and setup a viewer (emission) material to show its normals:
[image: Raw Normal Example]
It shouldn't be too surprising that the face pointing up is blue (RGB 0, 0, 1), the face pointing left is red (RGB 1, 0, 0) and the face pointing forward is green (RGB 0, 1, 0). Note the absolute vector node so we can see negative colors. We can also see magenta (RGB 0.5, 0, 0.5) and other colors on the bevels.

Now add in a checkerboard texture as a bump map:
[image: the bump map]

And look the effect that has on the normals:
[image: Bump mapped normals]
The areas where the checkerboard is solid white or solid black have the same normal values as the unbumped example. The only changes to the normals occur where there is a color transition. So in effect, the bump mapping node acts like a directed edge detector for its input image.

*unit is left a little vague here, a pixel on the UV map might seem ideal, but it really depends on how the object was unwrapped.

** disclaimer: I did not read Blenders code, this is based on general principles.

Comment: So it basically takes both a point/pixel from the texture and 2 points close to the point/pixel on the mesh we are shading to sort of get a local 'angle' since the bump map doesnt have a way of telling WHERE exactly it points, just the magnitude or height of how much it points?

Comment: I believe it's using 3 points from the texture to determine the angle, where closeness must come from the UV unwrapped geometry, so the texture points may not actually be nearby on the image if the mesh point lies near a UV seam.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean exactly again? If bump map values dont tell us direction, how does using 3 points from the bump map texture give us direction/angle?

Comment: I edited in a paragraph to the answer, does that help?

Comment: Regarding your edit, if we add that direction vector to the mesh normal, wont that give us a vector with a magnitude greater than 1? Shouldnt normal vectors have a magnitude = 1?

And what specfic linear algebra operation did we do to combine those 3 points to give us (-0.45,-0.89, 0.09) exactly?

Comment: Regarding your second edit, does this mean, we basically form a 'triangle' out of 3 pixels on the bump map, and find the normal of that 'triangle' and then 'mix' that with the actual mesh's pixel's normal to perturb it to find the new normal?

Comment: You have the right idea. I added a simple node setup to let you explore this concept a little more.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I had also tried researching this topic elsewhere and from what I saw there, it is mentioned that the reason we take a pixel above and another to the left of a pixel like you described (the formation of a 'triangle' on the bump map) is to measure these partial derivative things in each axis

I noticed you had also mentioned we only notice a 'bump' on the mesh picture only if there is a CHANGE in bump values, which lines up with the idea of derivatives. But how can I conflate the idea of derivatives with that of the bump map 'triangle'? I struggle at that.

Comment: Since the bitmap is not a continuous function we cannot take the derivative (or gradient) at a given point, the best we can do is a numerical estimation by seeing the change from the current pixel value to the one on the left we estimate ∂u, and by seeing the change from the current pixel to the one above we estimate ∂v. This gives us a simple estimate of the gradient [∂u, ∂v].

Comment: Since we basically have to measure the partial deriviatives by taking into account the pixel to the top and to the left we are sampling, does this mean if I sample, say, 700 pixels to apply on a mesh, I am essentially reading 2100 pixels in total? (Because I measure 3 pixels for every pixel on the bump map). Is this why we use normal maps? Because those we only read one pixel for every pixel rather than 3 here?

Comment: The math is pretty straightforward and simple. Video cards are great at this kind of thing. Normal maps are harder to create, but tend to be more powerful, especially when you want long tilted or curved panels or otherwise fake geometry. Bump maps are easier to create but work better at seams and surface imperfections.

Comment: How do bump and normal maps differ? If bump map values are converted to normals, and normal map values are simply read as normals, does this not mean the end product is the same? Why do they each excel at specific tasks? Why can't a normal map for instance perform surface imperfections?

Comment: Bump maps are much easier to create, a decent artist could create one in MS Paint. Normal maps are much harder, generally involving creating high resolution geometry and baking the map. Surface imperfections are fairly straight forward by plugging noise, Voronoi or other procedural texture into a bump node. Baking a normal map to represent, for example, the texturing of a sprayed ceiling, from high res geometry... not fun or perhaps even possible.

Comment: I see. So the issue with normal maps for surface imperfections is that attempting to bake a normal map to recreate tiny surface imperfections would be very hard, if I am assuming right?

And as one final last question, we take the partial derivative on each axis per pixel on a bump map to calculate the normal by theory. You  also described another method to find the normal by assuming the pixel to the left and pixel to up as vertices of a triangle, and finding the normal of that 'triangle' by crossproducting the edges. How is the latter method equivalent to finding derivatives?

Comment: To clarify my question further, both these methods give us the 'normal' from a bumpmap value. Therefore logically both these methods MUST be the same. But I struggle to understand exactly how crossproducting edges  is equivalent to taking partial derivatives. Are they two different methods that lead to the same result or are they the same ?